# Proof of optimal integral solutions for a linear problem

Tags: math, optimization, linear-programming

I am dealing with a minimization problem with objective cx. Vector c has all non-zero, positive and integer entries. My constraint equations are of the form Ax=b, with A the constraint matrix, b an integer vector where the first entry is a number larger than or equal to 2 and the remaining entries are 1, furthermore 0<=x<=1. Matrix A has one row where each entry is 1, the entries of the other rows are 1 or 0. Each column has at least one "1" entry, besides the "1" in the first row. Furthermore, A should be composed such that it should be possible to have at least one integer feasible solution.

Each column corresponds with a bus that is assigned to several passengers, corresponding with each row. The first constraint makes sure that exactly a certain number of buses are selected, and the other constraints make sure every passenger is assigned to a bus. Each entry in vector c is the cost of choosing a bus.

For example:

A=
1 1 1 1,
0 1 0 1,
1 1 0 0,
0 0 1 0,
1 0 0 0,
0 1 0 1

b=
3
1
1
1
1
1

This is an example with 4 possible buses and 5 passengers. Exactly 3 buses need to be selected, and all passengers need to be assigned to a bus. An integer feasible solution is selecting bus 1,3 and 4.

I am trying to find a way to proof and/or find out whether my linear program (LP) optimization problem always yields integer, in this case binary, solutions. In all of the instances I have tested, the solution to the relaxed model is integer.

I checked totally unimoudularity (TU), but it appears the constraint matrix A is not TU. A possibility is that the model is total dual integral (TDI). Does anybody know if there are some useful theorems to proof TUI or, in general, that my model always yields integer solutions ?

Comment: => https://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Updated example for the edit.

AFAICT nothing fundamental has really changed since the edit. You can find such examples by also including a row that is just the sum of the variables whose column length would otherwise be 1 (`c10` in the example below). (There are other ways of doing this, and this stops corresponding exactly to the description below, but it happens to satisfy the criteria you have given). This is a harder search problem, but random is still able to find an answer after a couple thousand guess and check rounds.

I was able to slap together a script around glpk to automate the search. If you have further variants, you may want to try to validate these using a similar method.

Here is the IP:

```
Minimize
  obj: x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6 + x7
Subject To
    c1: x2 + x3 + x7 = 1
    c2: x3 + x5 + x7 = 1
    c3: x1 + x5 + x7 = 1
    c4: x2 + x3 + x5 = 1
    c5: x1 + x4 + x7 = 1
    c6: x1 + x2 + x4 = 1
    c7: x1 + x2 + x7 = 1
    c8: x1 + x4 + x7 = 1
    c9: x3 + x4 + x7 = 1
    c10: x6 = 1
    c11: x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6 + x7 = 3
Bounds
0 <= x1 <= 1
0 <= x2 <= 1
0 <= x3 <= 1
0 <= x4 <= 1
0 <= x5 <= 1
0 <= x6 <= 1
0 <= x7 <= 1
BINARY
    x1
    x2
    x3
    x4
    x5
    x6
    x7
End
```

Here is an optimal LP solution:

```
     1 x1           NL             0             0             1         < eps
     2 x2           B            0.5             0             1
     3 x3           B              0             0             1
     4 x4           B            0.5             0             1
     5 x5           B            0.5             0             1
     6 x6           B              1             0             1
     7 x7           B            0.5             0             1
```

Here is an optimal IP solution:

```
     1 x1           *              1             0             1
     2 x2           *              0             0             1
     3 x3           *              1             0             1
     4 x4           *              0             0             1
     5 x5           *              0             0             1
     6 x6           *              1             0             1
     7 x7           *              0             0             1
```

---

Thanks for the fun problem. My answer is a bit long and follows the steps I tried.

The integer answers to this are quite computationally powerful, and they can be used to solve NP-complete problems. [One-in-three positive 3-SAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem#Exactly-1_3-satisfiability) is NP-complete. Lets reduce solve an N variable instance to solving (N-1) instances of this problem + an additional polynomial time check. Given the clause `exactly one of (x1 or x2 or x3)`, this is equivalent to the row `x1 + x2 + x3 = 1` for binary variables x1, x2, and x3. The matrix formed by these rows will be `A' x = 1`. If this is feasible it is satisfied with 1 to N variables set to true. For k=3 to N, try an instance with the all 1 coefficient row to be equal to k, `x1 + ... + xN = k`. Add this row to `A' x = 1` to get a problem instance `Ak x = b`. Each `Ak v = b` is of the form you have given. For k=1 (and k=2), just guess and check each variable (or pair of variables) to be the uniquely set to 1 variable(s). As LP is in P, if the LP solutions happened to always be integer, then you could combine all of this into a P-time algorithm for an NP-complete problem.

You can use the above as a starting place to look for counter examples. One can start generating random One-in-three positive 3-SAT clauses, use the encoding above, guess a `k`, make up a cost function c, and run it through an LP solver until you get feasible LPs with non-integer assignments. You can generate counter examples reasonably quickly once you go above 5 variables variables and constraints.

Example input.lp where we guessed k=3, and an objective function of x1 + x2:

```
Maximize
  obj: x1 + x2
Subject To
    c1: x1 + x3 + x5 = 1
    c2: x3 + x4 + x5 = 1
    c3: x1 + x3 + x5 = 1
    c4: x1 + x3 + x5 = 1
    c5: x1 + x3 + x5 = 1
    c6: x3 + x5 + x6 = 1
    c7: x3 + x4 + x6 = 1
    c8: x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6 = 3
Bounds
0 <= x1 <= 1
0 <= x2 <= 1
0 <= x3 <= 1
0 <= x4 <= 1
0 <= x5 <= 1
0 <= x6 <= 1
End
```

Selected output from `glpsol --lp short.lp -o local; cat local`:

```
   No. Column name  St   Activity     Lower bound   Upper bound    Marginal
------ ------------ -- ------------- ------------- ------------- -------------
     1 x1           B            0.5             0             1
     2 x2           NU             1             0             1           0.5
     3 x3           B              0             0             1
     4 x5           B            0.5             0             1
     5 x4           B            0.5             0             1
     6 x6           B            0.5             0             1
```

The assignment is the Activity column. You can see several variables assigned to 0.5 in the linear relaxtion.

After seeing the random instance, I suspect there are much simpler counter examples out there.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! However, I am dealing with a minimization problem rather than a maximization problem. Furthermore, I apologize I did not explain my problem clearly enough (I have made some edits in the post), but the the objective vector c should have all positive non-zero entries and the columns of A should have at least 2 non zero entries (counting the first row). Furthermore, A should be composed such that it should be possible to have at least one integer feasible solution. My question still remains though if the optimal is still integer.